# How to widen the terminal window in Cloud9 IDE?

Tags: view, terminal, cloud9-ide, nitrousio, cloud9

Is there a layout in the Cloud9 IDE that will widen the terminal window to the full width of the browser? (similar to how Nitrous.io used to look, picture attached). Wondering if this is possible in the C9 settings.

[image: Nitrous.io full width terminal window]

Answer (score 0):

If you click on the **Workspace** panel on the left side, you can hide your files, thus allowing the terminal to be nearly full screen. Otherwise, the terminal is confined to be nearly full-screen.

Answer (score 0):

you can use the following init script to change the cloud9 layout

```
var layout = services.layout
var s = layout.getElement("searchRow")
var c = layout.getElement("consoleRow")
var cp = c.parentNode
var h = layout.getElement("hboxMain")
var hp = h.parentNode

cp.removeChild(c)
s.parentNode.removeChild(s)
cp.insertBefore(s, cp.firstChild)
hp.removeChild(h)
hp.appendChild(c)
c.insertBefore(h, c.firstChild)
```

use `Cloud9>Open your init script` menu item to edit it.
Then save and press `ctrl-enter` (`cmd-enter`on mac).